# How can i simplify pins in maps

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin

So I have implemented Google Maps on my VS Xamarin project.
I know there is a way to simplify my code but I don't know how more could I do it.
I have a bunch of markers on my map and each time I create one I create at whole so I want to simplify this process and if possible extract the information from an excel file.

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;

namespace ------
{
    
    [DesignTimeVisible(false)]
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Position position = new Position(36.9628066, -122.0194722);
            MapSpan mapSpan = new MapSpan(position, 0.01, 0.01);
            Map map = new Map(mapSpan)
            {
               MapType = MapType.Hybrid
            
            };
            Content = map;
            Pin pin = new Pin
            {
                Label = "Santa HEY MAN",
                Address = "The city with a boardwalk",
                Type = PinType.Place,
                Position = new Position(36.9628066, -122.0194722)
            };
            map.Pins.Add(pin);

            Pin pin2 = new Pin
            {
                Label = "USA",
                Address = "2020",
                Type = PinType.Place,
                Position = new Position(36.9628066, -122.0194722)
            };
            map.Pins.Add(pin2);


        }

    }
}
```

Here I only show 2 pins but in reality, I have 30 pins.
How could I make this simpler?
Thanks a lot!
:)

Comment: create a json file with your pin data, read it and loop through it creating a pin for each data element

Comment: @Jason could you please elaborate a bit. I didn't understand.

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**note** this is all pseudocode, not syntactically correct json/C#

first, create a json file with your data and include it in your project

```
[ 
  { Label = "USA" Address = "2020", Lat = "36.9628066" Long = "-122.0194722" },
  ... 
  { Label = ""Santa HEY MAN", Address = "The city with a boardwalk", Lat = "36.9628066" Long = "-122.0194722} }
]
```

then, in your code

```
// read the file
var json = File.ReadAllText(path);

// deserialize using NewtonSoft
var places = DeserializeObject<List<Place>>(json);

// then create pins
foreach (var place in places)
{
   var pin = new Pin
        {
            Label = place.Label,
            Address = place.Address,
            Type = PinType.Place,
            Position = new Position(place.Lat, place.Long)
        };
   map.Pins.Add(pin);
}
```