# The type or namespace name 'Places' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, android, oop, xamarin

I have a very simple code and some very simple files.
I have created  a C# file to  insert some data and make a collection of pins from it but when I do it, it gives me this error:

> Error  CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Places' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

**My code:**

**DATA.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Orbage
{
    class DATA
    {
        string Label = "USA",
            Address = "This is the US",
            Lat = "40.060407",
            Lng = "-102.453091";
    }
}
```

**MapPage.cs**(*here is the error*)

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Orbage
{
    class MapPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MapPage()
        {
            CustomMap customMap = new CustomMap
            {
                MapType = MapType.Street

            };
            // ...
            Content = customMap;

            var json = File.ReadAllText("DATA");

            var places = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Places>>(json);
            foreach (var place in places)
            {
                CustomPin pin = new CustomPin
                {
                    Type = PinType.Place,
                    Position = new Position(place.lat,place.lng),
                    Label = place.Label,
                    Address = place.Address,
                    Name = "Xamarin",

                    Url = "http://xamarin.com/about/"
                };

                customMap.CustomPins = new List<CustomPin> { pin };

                customMap.Pins.Add(pin);
                customMap.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(37.79752, -122.40183), Distance.FromMiles(1.0)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I guess this all the code which is needed. I hope this is enough.

I used the following answers as reference:

- [deserialize-json-object-xamarin-android-c-sharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38743280/deserialize-json-object-xamarin-android-c-sharp)
- [how-can-i-simplify-pins-in-maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63300677/how-can-i-simplify-pins-in-maps)

Comment: I think it should be Data not Places in line DeserializeObject<List<Places>>(json);

Comment: I tried that it doesn't work just triggers more errors. Anything more I could do please tell me

Comment: When I put data in place of Place then the error comes as in the labels.Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0122 'DATA.Label' is inaccessible due to its protection level

Comment: first, in my response `Place` is a custom model that you need to write.  Second, in your code you are initializing `CustomPins` **inside** the loop, which isn't right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lot of issues in your code.

I am trying to fix only related to the question you have raised.

It should be `DATa` not `Place`, you need to declare the properties as `public` and change from `lat` to `Lat` and so....

```
class DATA
{
    public string Label = "USA";
    public string Address = "This is the US";
    public string Lat = "40.060407";
    public string Lng = "-102.453091";
}


var places = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DATA>>(json);
                foreach (var place in places)
                {
                    CustomPin pin = new CustomPin
                    {
                        Type = PinType.Place,
                        Position = new Position(place.Lat, place.Lng),
                        Label = place.Label,
                        Address = place.Address,
```

Comment: it then says that cannot convert from string to double.

Comment: Um. I did spend 2 hours trying to write the codes... and when I couldn't solve it I asked it in StackOverflow. I tried fidgeting till the least error came which was abt the data now as you said that this comes. I googled it up but I didn't understand how that StackOverflow question was related to my code..... Please don't say I didn't do research its my 1st time using Xamarin so I am bit confused.....Thats just that. I tried my best,,.

Comment: @ItsRaptorman please ask a new question, My answer solves your original issue