# how to fix 'DATA' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

Tags: c#, xamarin

This error followed after my last question occurred, I have collected data of pins in a C# file:
DATA.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Narbage
{
    public class DATA
    {
            public string Label = "USA";
            public string Address = "This is the US";
            public string Lat = "40.060407";
            public string Lng = "-102.453091";

        



    }
```

and this is the MapPage where all the data is:
Mappage.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Globalization;

namespace Orbage
{
    class MapPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MapPage()
        {
            CustomMap customMap = new CustomMap
            {
                MapType = MapType.Street

            };
            // ...
            Content = customMap;

            var json = File.ReadAllText(DATA);
            var places = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DATA>>(json);
            foreach (var place in places)
            {
                CustomPin pin = new CustomPin
                {
                    Type = PinType.Place,
                    Position = new Position(Double.Parse(place.Lat), Double.Parse(place.Lng)),
                    Label = place.Label,
                    Address = place.Address,
                    Name = "Xamarin",

                    Url = "http://xamarin.com/about/"
                };



                customMap.CustomPins = new List<CustomPin> { pin };

                customMap.Pins.Add(pin);
                customMap.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(37.79752, -122.40183), Distance.FromMiles(1.0)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here I get the error now I am new to Xamarin and I  previously used to code Java.
This is a simple syntax error but how to fix it?
I couldn't find any docs regarding reading a c# file.
Thnx a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DATA` is a class.  `ReadAllText` expects a string file path

```
var json = File.ReadAllText(DATA);
```

should be

```
var json = File.ReadAllText("some_file_path");
```

> I couldn't find any docs regarding reading a c# file

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/files?tabs=windows
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/workingwithfiles/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: So what can i do to collect all the pin info?

Comment: ?? Also how do you know this fast that I asked the question? Anyways Thanks a lot :D

Comment: if you are trying to follow my earlier response, I suggested a json file containing your data.  Do you have that?  That is what the "ReadAllText" line should be doing, reading that file.  I'm not sure why you are hardcoding values in the DATA class.

Comment: Yes I was trying to do exactly that. So a json file and not a C# oh.

Comment: that is **exactly** what I suggested in your first question.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63300677/how-can-i-simplify-pins-in-maps

Comment: how to add a json file in a xamarin project.

Comment: also how can I create a json file?

Comment: just add a text file to your platform project.  There are numerous tools you can use to create a json file, or just do it in a text editor.  You can even create the data in excel and then transform it into json.